# Number of points on $Y^2 = X^3 + A$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Let
$p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ be prime and let $A\in\mathbb{F}^{∗}_p$
. Show that the number of points
(including the point at infinity) on the curve
$Y^2
=
X^
3
+
A$
over
$\mathbb{F}_
p$
is exactly
$p
+ 1$

I'm having trouble bring in the fact that $p
\equiv 2
\pmod 3$

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: @tc1729 How do you know it's $p \equiv 1$ rather than $p \equiv 2$?  Let's see if the OP will clarify.

Comment: @ErickWong Yes sorry you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiplicative group of $\Bbb{F}_p$ is cyclic of order $p-1$. As $p\equiv2\pmod3$, this is not a multiple of three. Therefore cubing is a bijection from $\Bbb{F}_p$ to itself. Hence for each $Y$ ($p$ choices) there is a unique solution $X\in\Bbb{F}_p$, namely the cube root of $Y^2-A$. Including the point at infinity gives a total of $p+1$ solutions.